# "Authentication credentials were not provided": how can I make all the views to require log in in DRF?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to restrict the post view to only those who have logged in, however after I added the permission to only 'IsAuthenticated' I get this when I go to the url:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Of course, when I go there I have already logged in so something is not working but I'm not sure what. How can I make it so that users can see the posts only if the logged in?

This is the view of the post and the log in:

```
class UserLoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"status": status.HTTP_200_OK, "Token": token.key})

class PostAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """PostViewSet
        Post API will be used to creating new discussion, listing, and replying to a post
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = self.request.user

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        """
        return Post.objects.filter(reply_to__isnull=True)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': str(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

The URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('post/', views.PostAPIView.as_view(), name='post'),
]
```

I have these in my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: Are you sure the frontend is correctly storing the token received after the login, and sending/using it when calling your other endpoint which requires auth?

Comment: @JordanKowal How can I check that? I only have the API view so far that's in the views I posted.

Comment: Oh I see. The issue might be that you're going on the API interface, you go at the `login` URL, you input a valid username/password. The service returns the token, but your browser probably doesnt store it anywhere. So any subsequent API call anywhere is as if you were not logged in

Comment: You could probably test it by writing another python script which uses `requests`, call your `login` endpoint, get the token, and then call the `post` endpoint while including the token in your `requests.get` to see if your login actually worked

Comment: @JordanKowal Oh, I see, I will try that then. Thank you for the insight!